# Pivot a pandas DataFrame to be the correct format: `DataError: No numeric types to aggregate`

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pivot

Here is a pandas DataFrame I would like to manipulate:

```
import pandas as pd

data = {"grouping": ["item1", "item1", "item1", "item2", "item2", "item2", "item2", ...],
        "labels": ["A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C", "D", ...],
        "count": [5, 1, 8, 3, 731, 189, 9, ...]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

print(df)
>>>   grouping            labels       count
0        item1             A            5
1        item1             B            1
2        item1             C            8
3        item2             A            3
4        item2             B          731
5        item2             C          189
6        item2             D            9
7        ...               ...         ....
```

I would like to "unfold" this dataframe into the following format:

```
grouping    A    B    C    D
item1       5    1    8    3
item2       3    731  189  9
....        ........
```

How would one do this? I would think that this would work:

```
pd.pivot_table(df,index=["grouping", "labels"]
```

but I get the following error:

```
DataError: No numeric types to aggregate
```

Comment: Your example pivot table includes a value "3" under "D" that is not present in the original data (perhaps a typo).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are four idiomatic `pandas` ways to do this.

- No duplicates among grouping columns.  Does not require aggregation

  - `pivot`
  - `set_index`
- Duplicates among grouping columns. Does require aggregation

  - `pivot_table`
  - `groupby`

***`pivot`***

```
df.pivot('grouping', 'labels', 'count')
```

***`set_index`***

```
df.set_index(['grouping', 'labels'])['count'].unstack()
```

***`pivot_table`***

```
df.pivot_table('count', 'grouping', 'labels')
```

***`groupby`***

```
df.groupby(['grouping', 'labels'])['count'].sum().unstack()
```

All yield

```
labels      A      B      C    D
grouping                        
item1     5.0    1.0    8.0  NaN
item2     3.0  731.0  189.0  9.0
```

***timing***

[image]

With the `groupby`, `set_index`, or `pivot_table` approach, you can easily fill in missing values with `fill_value=0`

```
df.pivot_table('count', 'grouping', 'labels', fill_value=0)

df.groupby(['grouping', 'labels'])['count'].sum().unstack(fill_value=0)

df.set_index(['grouping', 'labels'])['count'].sum().unstack(fill_value=0)
```

All yield

```
labels    A    B    C  D
grouping                
item1     5    1    8  0
item2     3  731  189  9
```

---

Additional thoughts on `groupby`

Because we don't require any aggregation.  If we wanted to use `groupby`, we can minimize the impact of the implicit aggregation by utilizing a less impactful aggregator.

```
df.groupby(['grouping', 'labels'])['count'].max().unstack()
```

or

```
df.groupby(['grouping', 'labels'])['count'].first().unstack()
```

***timing `groupby`***

[image]

Comment: Woh! What is the reason for pivot to be so much faster than pivot_table?

Comment: Because `pivot` doesn't aggregate or attempt to aggregate.

Answer (score 6):

Use `set_index` and `unstack`:

```
df = df.set_index(['grouping','labels']).unstack().rename_axis(None)
df.columns = df.columns.droplevel()
print(df)
```

Output:

```
labels  A    B    C     D
item1   5    1    8  None
item2   3  731  189     9
```

Comment: This is nice, and much faster!+1

Comment: Thanks for this. For my df, I get `ValueError: Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape`

Comment: @ShanZhengYang Look at piRSquared answer.  He notes if you have duplicated data, then you are going to have to use pivot_table or groupby and choose your aggregation function.

Comment: I think this is a great answer though if one doesn't have duplicated data. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

You put `labels` in the index, but you want it in the columns:

```
>>> df.pivot_table(index='grouping', columns='labels')
         count                   
labels       A      B      C    D
grouping                         
item1      5.0    1.0    8.0  NaN
item2      3.0  731.0  189.0  9.0
```

Note that this makes the columns a MultiIndex.  If you don't want that, explicitly pass `values`: `df.pivot_table(index='grouping', columns='labels', values='count')`.

Also, note that the kind of reshape you seem to be looking for will only be possible if each combination of grouping and label has exactly one or zero values.  If any combination occurs more than once, you need to decide how to aggregate them (e.g., by summing the matching values).

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
In [1]: import pandas as pd
   ...: 
   ...: data = {"grouping": ["item1", "item1", "item1", "item2", "item2", "item2", "item2"],
   ...:         "labels": ["A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C", "D"],
   ...:         "count": [5, 1, 8, 3, 731, 189, 9]}
   ...: 
In [2]: df = pd.DataFrame(data)
In [3]: df.pivot_table(index="grouping",columns="labels")

Out[3]: 
             count              
    labels       A    B    C   D
    grouping                    
    item1        5    1    8 NaN
    item2        3  731  189   9
```