# Pivot non-numerical data with duplicates, without aggregation in pandas, keeping all duplicates

Tags: python, pandas

TLDR: I've been attempting to find a built-in solution to pivot non-numerical data with duplicates, without aggregation in pandas, keeping all duplicates w/o success. I carried out a custom operation but I'd like to find out if there's a better way.

I'd like to get my data from this format:

```
    CAT     FLDNAME Value
0   CAT 1   DIM1    A
1   CAT 1   DIM2    B
2   CAT 1   DIM2    C
3   CAT 2   DIM1    D
4   CAT 2   DIM2    E
5   CAT 2   DIM2
```

to

```
    CAT     DIM1    DIM2
0   CAT 1   A       B
1   CAT 1   A       C
2   CAT 2   D       E
2   CAT 2   D
```

Possibilities:

```
No duplicates among grouping columns. Does not require aggregation

 - pivot
 - set_index

Duplicates among grouping columns. Does require aggregation

 - pivot_table
 - groupby
```

as per piRSquared's summary in [Pivot a pandas DataFrame to be the correct format: `DataError: No numeric types to aggregate`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43457107/pivot-a-pandas-dataframe-to-be-the-correct-format-dataerror-no-numeric-types)

All the above methods require either non-unique indices when unstacking FLDNAME, or require aggregation. I also attempted using set_index with append=True and unstacking, but ended up with

```
    CAT     DIM1    DIM2
0   CAT 1   A       
1   CAT 1           B
2   CAT 1           C
3   CAT 2   D       
4   CAT 2           E
4   CAT 2
```

However, I used the following to create a DataFrame from the categories(CAT) and progressively renamed and left joined the grouped DIMs in FLDNAME.

```
cats = df.CAT.unique()
df2 = pd.DataFrame(cats, columns=['CAT'])

for i, grp in df.groupby('FLDNAME'):
    grp.columns = ['CAT', 'FLDNAME', i]
    df2 = df2.merge(grp[['CAT', i]], how='left', on='CAT')
```

Is there a better method that can be used out of the box?

Answer (score 1):

This is ugly!  Not my proudest moment.

```
cols = ['CAT', 'FLDNAME']
df.set_index(
    cols + [df.groupby(cols).cumcount()]
).Value.unstack('FLDNAME').ffill().reset_index(
    1, drop=True
).rename_axis(None, 1).reset_index()

     CAT DIM1 DIM2
0  CAT 1    A    B
1  CAT 1    A    C
2  CAT 2    D    E
```

Comment: I should have added in one more issue: the dataset I'm using contains nulls i.e not all the CATs have all DIMs and the values for some DIMs are specifically null, so the ffill will end up overwriting the null values. Sorry for being unclear. 


edit: Seems to work once I remove the ffill!